# Internationalizations for achievements

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, achievements

Trying to internationalize some open graph's achievements. I tried to put alternate `og:locale` as described in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/internationalization/.

When doing so, my open graph "achievements" objects are actually crawled with an alternate `fb_locale`, but only for the `en_US` locale, ignoring others.

Is this the proper way to perform internationalizations for achievements?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `locale` url variable like that:

```
https://graph.facebook.com?id=blah&locale=en_US
```